# How can I outline my figures?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics3d, color, image

I am currently producing some figures, all using the same colours. This, however makes them impossible to distingis from one another.

This is my code

```
plot1 = ListPointPlot3D[{Table[{1235.08, x, 
      PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]1, x]}, {x, 7800, 42800, 2}], 
    Table[{1265.88, x, PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]2, x]}, {x, 7800, 42800, 
      2}], Table[{1296.68, x, PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]3, x]}, {x, 7800, 
      42800, 2}], 
    Table[{1327.48, x, PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]4, x]}, {x, 7800, 42800, 
      2}], Table[{1358.28, x, PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]5, x]}, {x, 7800, 
      42800, 2}]}, 
   PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[{RGBColor[0.560181, 0.691569, 0.194885], Thick, 
      Dashed}], PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Bottom, ImageSize -> 600,
    AxesLabel -> {"Time (s)", "Separation (m)"}, 
   AxesStyle -> Directive[Bold, 18], 
   TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 12]];
plot2 = Graphics3D[{Thick, 
    Line[{{1235.08, 9260, 0}, {1358.28, 9260, 0}}]}];
Show[plot1, plot2, 
 PlotRange -> {{1235.08, 1358.28}, {7800, 42800}, {0, 0.00030}}]
```

and this is the resulting figure
[image: The figure resulting for the aforementioned code]

I think that a back line on the border of each PDF would make this figure way easier to read.

Any suggestion on imprving the figure is welcome.

Comment: Not specific to your question, but you could probably reduce your sampling rate without any appreciable change to the appearance. It looks like you're plotting over 15000 points per PDF. You could probably reduce that by a factor of 20 or more.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two things to add/adjust:

- FillingStyle
- PointSize

Since you're plotting points, not lines, Thickness/Thick and Dashing/Dashed won't have an effect. Try this for the PlotStyle:

```
PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[.01], RGBColor[0.560181, 0.691569, 0.194885]]
```

Now add a FillingStyle that will contrast with the PlotStyle, maybe something like this:

```
FillingStyle -> Lighter[RGBColor[0.560181, 0.691569, 0.194885], .7]
```

There will be some odd visual effects since you're generating a bunch of points with associated filling lines. If you want something smooth, you'll need to use a different plotting function